# discord.py reversing order of roles in userinfo command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was wondering how to reverse the order of the roles on my userinfo and I was trying to test things out with the indexing but I couldn't get it to work. I want it to display the highest role first and then lowest role last in that order.

```
@client.command(aliases=["profile"])
@commands.cooldown(1,5,BucketType.channel)
async def userinfo(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
  datetime_format = "%a, %d %b %Y"
  if member == None:
    member = ctx.author
  mstatus = str(member.status)
  l = [
  ["dnd", "<:dnd:831922557502488606> Do Not Disturb"],
  ["idle", "<:idle:831922612308541490> Idle"],
  ["online", "<:online:831922590041636865> Online"],
  ["offline", "<:offline:831922545803395133> Offline"]]
  for status in l:
    mstatus = mstatus.replace(status[0], status[1])
  try:
    roles = [role for role in member.roles[1:]]
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color(0xff3400),
    title = f"{member}")
    embed.add_field(name="**•ID•**", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Status•**", value=str(mstatus), inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.add_field(name="**•Account Created At•**", value=f"{member.created_at.strftime(datetime_format)}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Joined Server At•**", value=f"{member.joined_at.strftime(datetime_format)}", inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name=f"**•Highest Role•**", value = f"{member.top_role.mention}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"**•Roles• ({len(member.roles) - 1})**", value='• '.join([role.mention for role in roles]), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Account Created At•**", value=f"{member.created_at.strftime(datetime_format)}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Joined Server At•**", value=f"{member.joined_at.strftime(datetime_format)}", inline = True)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}", text = f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  except:
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color(0xff3400),
    title = f"{member}")
    embed.add_field(name="**•ID•**", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Status•**", value=str(mstatus), inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
    embed.add_field(name=f"**•Roles• (0)**", value="No roles", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Account Created At•**", value=f"{member.created_at.strftime(datetime_format)}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="**•Joined Server At•**", value=f"{member.joined_at.strftime(datetime_format)}", inline = True)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}", text = f"Requested by {ctx.author}")
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: Here's an example of what it looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse your `roles` list

```
# code before
try:
    roles = [role for role in member.roles[1:]]
    roles = roles[::-1] # reverse roles list
    embed = discord.Embed(
    color = discord.Color(0xff3400),
    title = f"{member}")
# code after
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists have a reverse method.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
mylist.reverse()
print(mylist)

>> 4 3 2 1
```